# Difference in WiFi performance across windows 10 dell machines, work and personal

Tags: wifi-configuration, dell-latitude, dell-vostro

I'd like to know where to start to understand why my work issued Dell Latitude 5280 Windows 10 machine seems to be much "happier" connecting to my home WiFi connection when compared to my newer Dell Vostro machine also running Windows 10.

To clarify what I mean by "happier", my personal Dell machine often struggles to connect to my WiFi range extender. Additionally, my work machine (that runs a corporate VPN all the time) keeps a strong connection to my WiFi at a much greater distance. The experience with my work machine is much more "just works" where I've had to troubleshoot and reset WiFi hardware on my personal machine.

It would be great to have more reliability with my personal laptop WiFi connection so keen to know where to start.

**Range Extender model**: Belkin f9k1015ukv1. This one is a plug in the wall and setup via WPS.

Comment: The Dell Vostro might have a weaker wifi adapter. You could try it with a good-quality USB wifi adapter to compare.

Comment: What if you connect directly to your main AP (probable on your "router") and not to the "extender"? Any difference then? what kind of "extender" is it? how is it connected to your network?

Comment: Added the model details. Direct connection to the main AP works very well.